# Trouble communicating by SOAP between Java and PHP

Tags: java, php, soap

Here's the most important ( I think ) part of the SOAP written in Java:

```
@WebService()
public class VremeaServerModule {

    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "getWeatherForCity")
    public String getWeatherForCity(@WebParam(name = "city") String city) throws IOException {
```

and here's the PHP code that issuing a SOAP request:

```
function getWeather($cityName)
{
  $wsdl_url = "some_url";
  $WSDL = new SOAP_WSDL($wsdl_url);
  $client = $WSDL->getProxy();
  $params = array("city" => $cityName);
  print_r($params);
  $result = $client->getWeatherForCity($params);
  return $result;
}
```

The thing is, Java always receives city as being null. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: what is printed in print_r and is cityName something that can be turned into a String?

Comment: The php snipet is part of a function, and cityName is a parameter (a string).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with just this:
    $result = $client->getWeatherForCity($cityName);

Comment: I'm not sure where the SOAP_WSDL comes from, but there's a standard PHP class for creating a soap client: SoapClient. (http://php.net/SoapClient) I have used it more than once, and I never experienced any problems with it. Parameters are just parameters to a function, and don't have to be put into an array first, like in your example. Maybe this can help you further?

Comment: I tried using this as well. The parameter continues to be null. I'm printing it before I send it from PHP, and it's showing me that it has a value. But when it gets to Java, printing the value of the name parameter, shows me null.